# Bash printf %q invalid directive

Tags: linux, bash, sed, printf, ps1

I want to change my PS1 in my .bashrc file.
I've found a script using printf with %q directive to escape characters :

```
#!/bin/bash
STR=$(printf "%q" "PS1=\u@\h:\w\$ ")
sed -i '/PS1/c\'"$STR" ~/.bashrc
```

The problem is that I get this error :

```
script.sh: 2: printf: %q: invalid directive
```

Any idea ? Maybe an other way to escape the characters ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `printf` command is built into bash. It's also an external command, typically installed in `/usr/bin/printf`. On most Linux systems, `/usr/bin/printf` is the GNU coreutils implementation.

Older releases of the GNU coreutils `printf` command do not support the `%q` format specifier; it was introduced in version 8.25, released 2016-10-20. bash's built-in `printf` command does -- and has as long as bash has had a built-in `printf` command.

The error message implies that you're running `script.sh` using something other than bash.

Since the `#!/bin/bash` line appears to be correct, you're probably doing one of the following:

```
sh script.sh
. script.sh
source script.sh
```

Instead, just execute it directly (after making sure it has execute permission, using `chmod +x` if needed):

```
./script.sh
```

Or you could just edit your `.bashrc` file manually. The script, if executed correctly, will add this line to your `.bashrc`:

```
PS1=\\u@\\h:\\w\$\
```

(The space at the end of that line is significant.) Or you can do it more simply like this:

```
PS1='\u@\h:\w\$ '
```

One problem with the script is that it will replace *every* line that mentions `PS1`. If you just set it once and otherwise don't refer to it, that's fine, but if you have something like:

```
if [ ... ] ; then
    PS1=this
else
    PS1=that
fi
```

then the script will thoroughly mess that up. It's just a bit too clever.

Comment: This is one of those situations where doing it manually is simpler and safer than doing it with a fancy command line. :)

Comment: RE: `The GNU coreutils printf command does not support the %q format specifier` The coreutils documentation now mentions the `%q` directive: https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/printf

Comment: @JanusTroelsen: Updated.

Answer (score 2):

Keith Thompson has given good advice in his answer. But FWIW, you can force bash to use a builtin command by preceding the command name with `builtin` eg

```
builtin printf "%q" "PS1=\u@\h:\w\$ "
```

<s>Conversely,</s>

`command printf "%s\n" some stuff`

forces bash to use the external command (if it can find one).

`command` can be used to invoke commands on disk when a *function* with the same name exists. However, `command` does **not** invoke a command on disk in lieu of a Bash built-in with the same name, it only works to suppress invocation of a shell function. (Thanks to Rockallite for bringing this error to my attention).

It's possible to enable or disable specific bash builtins (maybe your .bashrc is doing that to printf). See `help enable` for details. And I guess I should mention that you can use

```
type printf
```

to find out what kind of entity (shell function, builtin, or external command) bash will run when you give it a naked `printf`. You can get a list of all commands with a given name by passing `type` the `-a` option, eg

```
type -a printf
```

---

You can use grep to see the lines in your .bashrc file that contain PS1:

```
grep 'PS1' ~/.bashrc
```

or

```
grep -n0 --color=auto 'PS1=' ~/.bashrc
```

which gives you line numbers and fancy coloured output. And then you can use the line number to force sed to just modify the line you want changed.

Eg, if grep tells you that the line you want to change is line 7, you can do

```
sed -i '7c\'"$STR" ~/.bashrc
```

to edit it. Or even better,

```
sed -i~ '7c\'"$STR" ~/.bashrc
```

which backs up the original version of the file in case you make a mistake.

When using `sed -i` I generally do a test run first without the `-i` so that the output goes to the shell, to let me see what the modifications do before I write them to the file.

Comment: I don't think using `builtin printf` would help in this case. bash will use the builtin `printf` by default. If it's not using it in this case, it's because the shell being invoked isn't bash.

Comment: Well yeah. Unless it's been disabled during shell startup by `enable -n printf` for some weird reason. But I agree that your theory is more likely, I was just mentioning it as a possibility.

Comment: Hmm. Somehow I've managed to avoid learning about the `enable` command until now. Interesting.

Comment: I admit it is a bit obscure. I only learned about it recently myself: I stumbled across it in the bash man while I was looking up the details of some other builtin. I'm sure it'll come in handy one day... :)

Comment: `enable -n enable` is tempting.

Comment: ROFL! I guess using it temporarily would be ok, but I'd never set in .bashrc, as I generally try to avoid fiddling with default shell parameters that could interfere with script portability. And if you forget you've done stuff like that it can make debugging a PITA.

Comment: `command printf` also invokes the shell builtin. Run `command -V printf` and check it.

Comment: @Rockallite Oops! It looks like I didn't test that very well, did I? ;) I've repaired my answer. Thanks for bringing that blunder to my attention.

Comment: @KeithThompson FWIW, I had a mistake in this answer, but I've fixed it now.