# Is $(printf '%q ' "${@:1}") equivalent to "${*}"?

Tags: bash, shell, arguments, parameter-passing, posix

Is `$(printf '%q ' "${@:1}")` equivalent to `"${*}"`?

If they are, then, doing `$(printf '%q ' "${@:2}")` (note the 2 instead of 1 as before) is not possible with pure bash `$*`?

Related questions:

1. [POSIX sh equivalent for Bash’s printf %q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12162010/posix-sh-equivalent-for-bash-s-printf-q)
2. [How to use printf "%q " in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40573839/how-to-use-printf-q-in-bash)
3. [Bash printf %q invalid directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26068999/bash-printf-q-invalid-directive)
4. [How to make runuser correctly forward all command line arguments, instead of trying to interpret them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012929/how-to-make-runuser-correctly-forward-all-command-line-arguments-instead-of-try)
5. [How to portability use "${@:2}"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56822216/how-to-portability-use-2)

Comment: Why don't you just try it and see?

Comment: Using `"${*}"` (more usually written `"$*"`) yields a single string.  POSIX does not specify the `%q` conversion specification for either the `printf` command or the `printf()` function.  You have to refer to the documentation for your system to know what that's going to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not equivalent, because words are splitted. Ex. the following code:

```
check_args() {
  echo "\$#=$#"
  printf "%s\n" "$@";
}

# setting arguments
set -- "space notspace" "newline"$'\n'"newline"
echo '1: ---------------- "$*"'
check_args "$*"

echo '2: ---------------- $(printf '\''%q '\'' "${@:1}")'
check_args $(printf '%q ' "${@:1}")

echo '3: ---------------- "$(printf '\''%q '\'' "${@:1}")"'
check_args "$(printf '%q ' "${@:1}")"

echo '4: ---------------- IFS=@ and "$*"'
( IFS=@; check_args "$*"; )

echo "5: ---------------- duplicating quoted"
check_args "$(printf '%s'"${IFS:0:1}" "${@:1}" | sed 's/'"${IFS:0:1}"'$//')"

echo "6: ---------------- duplicating quoted IFS=@"
( IFS=@; check_args "$(printf '%s'"${IFS:0:1}" "${@:1}" | sed 's/'"${IFS:0:1}"'$//')"; )

echo "7: ---------------- duplicating eval unquoted"
eval check_args $(printf '%q"'"${IFS:0:1}"'"' "${@:1}" | sed 's/'"${IFS:0:1}"'$//')

echo "8: ---------------- duplicating eval unquoted IFS=@"
( eval check_args $(IFS=@ ; printf '%q"'"${IFS:0:1}"'"' "${@:1}" | sed 's/"'"${IFS:0:1}"'"$//'); )
```

will output:

```
1: ---------------- "$*"
$#=1
space notspace newline
newline
2: ---------------- $(printf '%q ' "${@:1}")
$#=3
space\
notspace
$'newline\nnewline'
3: ---------------- "$(printf '%q ' "${@:1}")"
$#=1
space\ notspace $'newline\nnewline'
4: ---------------- IFS=@ and "$*"
$#=1
space notspace@newline
newline
5: ---------------- duplicating quoted
$#=1
space notspace newline
newline
6: ---------------- duplicating quoted IFS=@
$#=1
space notspace@newline
newline
7: ---------------- duplicating eval unquoted
$#=1
space notspace newline
newline
8: ---------------- duplicating eval unquoted IFS=@
$#=1
space notspace@newline
newline
```

tested on [repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/DependentUtterControlpanel).

The `"$*"` outputs the arguments delimetered by IFS. So, shown in test `4`, if delimeter is not unset or set to space, then the output of `$*` will be delimetered by IFS, `@` in this example.

Also when IFS is unset or set to space, the output of `$*` does not include a terminating space, while `printf '%q '` will always print a trailing space on the end of the string.

The output of `$(printf '%q ' "${@:1}")` is still splitted on space. So the test case `2` receives 3 arguments, because the `space notspace` string is separated by space and splitted to two arguments. When enclosing the `printf` inside `"` will not help - `printf` substitutes ex. newlines for `\n` characters.

Cases `5`, `6`, `7`, `8` are my tries to replicate the behavior of `"$*"` using printf.  It can be seen with cases `7` and `8` I used `eval`, with cases `5` and `6` I quoted the command substitution. The output of cases ( `5` and `6` ) and ( `7` and `8` ) should match the output of cases `1` and `4` respectively.

For duplicating the behavior of `"$*"` special care needs to be taken for `IFS` to properly delimeter the strings. I used `sed 's/'"${IFS:0:1}"'$//'` to remove the trailing IFS separator from the `printf` output. The `5` and `6` cases are unquoted `$(printf ...)` tries, with `6` using `IFS=@` to show the separating works. The `7` and `8` cases use eval with special handling on the `IFS`, cause the `IFS` character itself needs to be enclosed with quotes, so the shell will not split on it again, that's why `printf '%q"'"${IFS:0:1}"'"'`.

> doing $(printf '%q ' "${@:2}") (note the 2 instead of 1 as before) is not possible with pure bash $*?

You probably could just shift the arguments inside the substitution  `$(shift; printf "%s\n" "$*")`, but as shown above, they are not equivalent anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Using [@Kamil Cuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9072753) answer as base, I built this new testing code for illustration, also [available on repl](https://repl.it/repls/VapidExpensiveBackground):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
check_args() {
  echo "\$#=$#"
  local counter=0
  for var in "$@"
  do
      counter=$((counter+1));
      printf "$counter. '$var', ";
  done
  printf "\\n\\n"
}

# setting arguments
set -- "space notspace" "lastargument"; counter=1
echo $counter': ---------------- "$*"'; counter=$((counter+1))
check_args "$*"

echo $counter': ---------------- $*'; counter=$((counter+1))
check_args $*

echo $counter': ---------------- "$@"'; counter=$((counter+1))
check_args "$@"

echo $counter': ---------------- $@'; counter=$((counter+1))
check_args $@

echo $counter': ---------------- $(printf '\''%q '\'' "${@:1}")'; counter=$((counter+1))
check_args $(printf '%q ' "${@:1}")

echo $counter': ---------------- "$(printf '\''%q '\'' "${@:1}")"'; counter=$((counter+1))
check_args "$(printf '%q ' "${@:1}")"

echo $counter': ---------------- IFS=@ and "$*"'; counter=$((counter+1))
( IFS=@; check_args "$*"; )

echo "$counter: ---------------- duplicating quoted"; counter=$((counter+1))
check_args "$(printf '%s'"${IFS:0:1}" "${@:1}" | sed 's/'"${IFS:0:1}"'$//')"

echo "$counter: ---------------- duplicating quoted IFS=@"; counter=$((counter+1))
( IFS=@; check_args "$(printf '%s'"${IFS:0:1}" "${@:1}" | sed 's/'"${IFS:0:1}"'$//')"; )

echo "$counter: ---------------- duplicating eval unquoted"; counter=$((counter+1))
eval check_args $(printf '%q"'"${IFS:0:1}"'"' "${@:1}" | sed 's/'"${IFS:0:1}"'$//')

echo "$counter: ---------------- duplicating eval unquoted IFS=@"; counter=$((counter+1))
( eval check_args $(IFS=@ ; printf '%q"'"${IFS:0:1}"'"' "${@:1}" | sed 's/"'"${IFS:0:1}"'"$//'); )
```

-->

```
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
1: ---------------- "$*"
$#=1
1. 'space notspace lastargument',

2: ---------------- $*
$#=3
1. 'space', 2. 'notspace', 3. 'lastargument',

3: ---------------- "$@"
$#=2
1. 'space notspace', 2. 'lastargument',

4: ---------------- $@
$#=3
1. 'space', 2. 'notspace', 3. 'lastargument',

5: ---------------- $(printf '%q ' "${@:1}")
$#=3
1. 'space', 2. 'notspace', 3. 'lastargument',

6: ---------------- "$(printf '%q ' "${@:1}")"
$#=1
1. 'space\ notspace lastargument ',

7: ---------------- IFS=@ and "$*"
$#=1
1. 'space notspace@lastargument',

8: ---------------- duplicating quoted
$#=1
1. 'space notspace lastargument',

9: ---------------- duplicating quoted IFS=@
$#=1
1. 'space notspace@lastargument',

10: ---------------- duplicating eval unquoted
$#=1
1. 'space notspace lastargument ',

11: ---------------- duplicating eval unquoted IFS=@
$#=1
1. 'space notspace@lastargument',
```