# How to portability use "${@:2}"?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, posix, shellcheck

On [Allow for ${@:2} syntax in variable assignment](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/issues/214) they say I should not use `"${@:2}"` because it breaks things across different shells, and I should use `"${*:2}"` instead.

But using `"${*:2}"` instead of `"${@:2}"` is nonsense because doing `"${@:2}"` is not equivalent to `"${*:2}"` as the [following example](https://repl.it/repls/PreviousEmbellishedLeads):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
check_args() {
  echo "\$#=$#"
  local counter=0
  for var in "$@"
  do
      counter=$((counter+1));
      printf "$counter. '$var', ";
  done
  printf "\\n\\n"
}

# setting arguments
set -- "space1 notspace" "space2 notspace" "lastargument"; counter=1
echo $counter': ---------------- "$*"'; counter=$((counter+1))
check_args "$*"

echo $counter': ---------------- "${*:2}"'; counter=$((counter+1))
check_args "${*:2}"

echo $counter': ---------------- "${@:2}"'; counter=$((counter+1))
check_args "${@:2}"
```

-->

```
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
1: ---------------- "$*"
$#=1
1. 'space1 notspace space2 notspace lastargument',

2: ---------------- "${*:2}"
$#=1
1. 'space2 notspace lastargument',

3: ---------------- "${@:2}"
$#=2
1. 'space2 notspace', 2. 'lastargument',
```

If I cannot use `"${@:2}"` ([as they say](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/issues/214)), what is the equivalent can I use instead?

This is original question [Process all arguments except the first one (in a bash script)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057387/process-all-arguments-except-the-first-one-in-a-bash-script) and their only answer to keep  arguments with spaces together is to use `"${@:2}"`

Comment: How portable do you *need* your script to be? Is it OK if it's bash-specific?

Comment: If it is not possible, most portable it can be, the best. It would be nice if it were POSIX portable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's context that's not clear in the question unless you follow the links. It's concerning [the following recommendation from shellcheck.net](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/issues/214):

```
local _help_text="${@:2}"
                  ^––SC2124 Assigning an array to a string! Assign as array, or use * instead of @ to concatenate.
```

Short answer: Don't assign lists of things (like arguments) to plain variables, use an array instead.

Long answer: Generally, `"${@:2}"` will get all but the first argument, with each treated as a separate item ("word"). `"${*:2}"`, on the other hand, produces a single item consisting of all but the first argument stuck together, separated by a space (or whatever the first character of `$IFS` is).

But in the specific case where you're assigning to a plain variable, the variable is only capable of storing a single item, so `var="${@:2}"` *also* collapses the arguments down to a single item, but it does it in a less consistent way than `"${*:2}"`. In order to avoid this, use something that is capable of storing multiple items: an array. So:

- Really bad: `var="${@:2}"`
- Slightly less bad: `var="${*:2}"`
- Much better: `arrayvar=("${@:2}")` (the parentheses make this an array)

Note: to get the elements of the array back, with each one treated properly as a separate item, use `"${arrayvar[@]}"`. Also, arrays are not supported by all shells (notably, `dash` doesn't support them), so if you use them you should be sure to use a bash shebang (`#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`). If you really need portability to other shells, things get *much* more complicated.

Answer (score 3):

Neither `${@:2}` nor `${*:2}` is portable, and many shells will reject both as invalid syntax.  If you want to process all arguments except the first, you should get rid of the first with a shift.

```
first="${1}"
shift
echo The arguments after the first are:
for x; do echo "$x"; done
```

At this point, the first argument is in "$first" and the positional parameters are shifted down one.

Answer (score 0):

This demonstrates how to combine all `${@}` arguments into a single variable one without the hack `${@:1}` or `${@:2}` ([live example](https://repl.it/repls/DetailedThirstyRegisters)):

```
#!/bin/bash

function get_all_arguments_as_single_one_unquoted() {
    single_argument="$(printf "%s " "${@}")";
    printf "unquoted arguments %s: '%s'\\n" "${#}" "${single_argument}";
}

function get_all_arguments_as_single_one_quoted() {
    single_argument="${1}";
    printf "quoted arguments %s: '%s'\\n" "${#}" "${single_argument}";
}

function escape_arguments() {
    escaped_arguments="$(printf '%q ' "${@}")";
    get_all_arguments_as_single_one_quoted "${escaped_arguments}";
    get_all_arguments_as_single_one_unquoted ${escaped_arguments};
}

set -- "first argument" "last argument";
escape_arguments "${@}";
```

`-->`

```
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
quoted arguments 1: 'first\ argument last\ argument '
unquoted arguments 4: 'first\ argument last\ argument '
```

As [@William Pursell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/140750) answer points out, if you would like to get only `{@:2}` arguments, you can add a `shift` call before `"${@}"`

```sh
function escape_arguments() {
    shift;
    escaped_arguments="$(printf '%q ' "${@}")";
    get_all_arguments_as_single_one_quoted "${escaped_arguments}";
    get_all_arguments_as_single_one_unquoted ${escaped_arguments};
}
```

`-->`

```
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
quoted arguments 1: 'last\ argument '
unquoted arguments 2: 'last\ argument '
```