# Jenkins bug or intended behaviour? possible different version of bash on pipeline

Tags: bash, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to do some stuff on the pipeline but I thinking that I'm hitting a bug.
I don't think that is a intended behaviour because it will kinda defeat the purpose of using docker or a docker worker.

My pipeline for test this.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'node'
                    label 'docker'
                }
            }
            steps {
                sh """ printf "%q%s" "/path with space" "/out-file.js" """
                
                sh(script: """
                        #!/bin/bash
                        printf "%q%s" "/path with space" "/out-file.js"
                    """)
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I get this on the logs

```
+ printf %q%s /path with space /out-file.js
/user/builds/workspace/test@tmp/durable-6f010694/script.sh: 1: printf: %q: invalid directive
```

But if I run

```sh
$ docker run -it --rm node bash
root@c8e43eaefbae:/# printf "%q%s\n" "/path with space" "/out-file.js"
/path\ with\ space/out-file.js
root@c8e43eaefbae:/#
```

Works fine, the version of bash in the node container accepts the `%q` but when running from jenkins I get this error.

It's like if jenkins is using his own version of bash instead of the version from the container.

Looking on the web I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26069697/1518284) talking about version.

But running this command `dpkg -s coreutils | grep -i version` on the pipeline and on the docker run it gives the same version `8.26-3`

```
...
sh "dpkg -s coreutils | grep -i version"
sh "npm --version"
sh "/bin/bash --version"
...
jenkins logs:
    [Pipeline] {
    [Pipeline] sh
    + + grepdpkg -i version -s coreutils
    Version: 8.26-3
    [Pipeline] sh
    + npm --version
    7.0.3
    + /bin/bash --version
    GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
    Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
    License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later 
    <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

or

root@c8e43eaefbae:/# dpkg -s coreutils | grep -i version
Version: 8.26-3
root@c8e43eaefbae:/#
root@c8e43eaefbae:/# /bin/bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
```

Before open a issue on jenkins I would like to know if this is the intended behaviour, I'm doing something wrong or if it's really a bug.

---

Jenkins 2.249.2
Docker Desktop for MAC 2.4.0.0 (48506)
engine 19.03.13
compose 1.27.4

Running compose with a jenkins (jenkins/jenkins:lts), a nginx (nginx:latest) to route a pretty domain name and docker (docker:stable) as worker

Comment: Run bash --version in both environments to confirm that they are both the same,

Comment: Edited with bash version, it's the same.

Comment: You have a typo in your string quotes. You need to cast multi-line literal strings there with `'''`.